# python ast module fails in pydev, succeeds in cmdline python

Tags: python, pydev

This is weird. I run this program in PyDev

```
import ast
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print sys.version
    src = '''
print 3*4+5**2
'''
    print dir(ast)
    n = ast.parse(src)
    print n
```

and it outputs:

```
2.7.5 |Anaconda 1.6.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 31 2013, 10:45:37) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ["C:\research\ast\ast\test1.py", line 16, in <module>
    n = ast.parse(src)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parse'
```

but when I run it in cmdline it prints this:

```
C:\research\ast\ast>python test1.py
2.7.5 |Anaconda 1.6.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 31 2013, 10:45:37) [MSC v.1500 64
bit (AMD64)]
['AST', 'Add', 'And', 'Assert', 'Assign', 'Attribute', 'AugAssign', 'AugLoad', '
AugStore', 'BinOp', 'BitAnd', 'BitOr', 'BitXor', 'BoolOp', 'Break', 'Call', 'Cla
ssDef', 'Compare', 'Continue', 'Del', 'Delete', 'Dict', 'DictComp', 'Div', 'Elli
psis', 'Eq', 'ExceptHandler', 'Exec', 'Expr', 'Expression', 'ExtSlice', 'FloorDi
v', 'For', 'FunctionDef', 'GeneratorExp', 'Global', 'Gt', 'GtE', 'If', 'IfExp',
'Import', 'ImportFrom', 'In', 'Index', 'Interactive', 'Invert', 'Is', 'IsNot', '
LShift', 'Lambda', 'List', 'ListComp', 'Load', 'Lt', 'LtE', 'Mod', 'Module', 'Mu
lt', 'Name', 'NodeTransformer', 'NodeVisitor', 'Not', 'NotEq', 'NotIn', 'Num', '
Or', 'Param', 'Pass', 'Pow', 'Print', 'PyCF_ONLY_AST', 'RShift', 'Raise', 'Repr'
, 'Return', 'Set', 'SetComp', 'Slice', 'Store', 'Str', 'Sub', 'Subscript', 'Suit
e', 'TryExcept', 'TryFinally', 'Tuple', 'UAdd', 'USub', 'UnaryOp', 'While', 'Wit
h', 'Yield', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '
__version__', 'alias', 'arguments', 'boolop', 'cmpop', 'comprehension', 'copy_lo
cation', 'dump', 'excepthandler', 'expr', 'expr_context', 'fix_missing_locations
', 'get_docstring', 'increment_lineno', 'iter_child_nodes', 'iter_fields', 'keyw
ord', 'literal_eval', 'mod', 'operator', 'parse', 'slice', 'stmt', 'unaryop', 'w
alk']
<_ast.Module object at 0x0000000002A99EB8>
```

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Do you have an `ast.py` file somewhere (except in Python's library dir)? Try printing `os.path.abspath(ast.__file__)`.

Comment: that's it! DOH! I named the project ast instead of ast_test

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems the `ast` you have imported in PyDev is not the ast module in the standard library, but a package.

I guess:

> There is a `__init__.py` file in the same directory as your test1.py.
>   You selected "Add project directory to the PYTHONPATH" during the project creation.

These two combined, results in that error. The ast module in the standard library is shadowed by this `ast` package.

In cmdline python, this `ast` package is not in the search path, thus the ast module is imported.

If you change test1.py to

```
import ast

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ast.__file__
```

I guess the output in PyDev would be

```
C:\research\ast\ast\__init__.pyc
```

Comment: I just ran into this problem by absentmindedly naming the script where I was going to play with AST for the first time... ast.py. once I renamed it and deleted ast.pyc I was back in business. A facepalm moment but hopefully this comment helps somebody someday.